# Showing that the space of $C^1$ solutions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ of the DDE $f’(x)=f(x+1)$ is infinite-dimensional

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

I’d like to show that the space of $C^1$ solutions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ of the delay differential equation $f’(x)=f(x+1)$ is infinite-dimensional.

I think this can be done by using the fact that there exists an infinite number of solutions to the equation $e^z-z=0$, where $z \in \mathbb{C}$, which I’ve already shown… but I haven’t managed to find the good argument so far.

Edit: I guess the idea must be something like assuming the solution is $ f(x)= {\rm e}^{\lambda x } $ and substituting in the equation to get $ \lambda {\rm e}^{\lambda x } = {\rm e}^{\lambda (x+1) }$, that is $\lambda = {\rm e}^{\lambda } $, which as I said has infinitely many complex solutions. But I’m not sure this is all there is to it…

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It suffices to find infinitely many solutions that are linearly independent.

As you point out, each root $\lambda$ of the equation $$e^{\lambda}=\lambda\tag{*}$$ gives a solution $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$; you need to show that these are linearly independent.

One way to do this is to consider a purported dependence relation: $$0=\sum_{j\in J}{a_je^{\lambda_j x}}$$ where (1) $J$ is finite, (2) each $\lambda_j$ solves (*), and (3) there is no $j$ for which $a_j=0$.

Pick the $\lambda_j$ with largest real part and divide by $e^{\lambda_j x}$.  Now take $x\to\infty$.  What happens?

Comment: We’d be left with $a_j=0$ for the corresponding $j$? Which would be a contradiction I guess.

Comment: $J$ would be any finite subset of the set of solutions?

Comment: A minor comment: note that $\lambda_j$ is never real, but you speak about the largest.

Comment: @Hokoro: exactly.

Comment: @JohnB: Oops.  Thanks for the catch.